# Drop event from outside window only fires the second time

Tags: javascript, textarea

I am drag-and-dropping some text from a proprietary application into an HTML `<textarea>` element. This software cannot copy-paste; drag-and-drop is the only option. However, the drag and drop can be simulated by simply typing a few lines in Word, then dragging them into the browser.

I have a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8dL1ef4u/8/) with my code. However, when I drag some lines from the program into the text box *the first time*, I get "undefined" returned. When I try it again without reloading the page (when the text area already has contents), it works great.

How can I get it to work the first time?

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the line

```
$('#return').html(dropstr);
```

inside of the getAsString callback.

```js
var dropstr;
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#dropbox').on('drop', function(e) {
        e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.items[0].getAsString(function(str){
            dropstr=str; 
         console.log(dropstr);
            $('#return').html(dropstr);
        });
    });
});
```

```css
#return{
  
  border:1px solid black;
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="dropbox" contenteditable="true" id="dropbox">
<textarea></textarea>
</div>

<div id="return">

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You were appending outside of callback which itself is not needed at least in your case. [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/npa2jwyz/3/)

```
<div id="dropbox" contenteditable="true" id="dropbox">
  <textarea></textarea>
</div>

<div id="return">

</div>
```

and here is js.

```
var dropstr;
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#dropbox').on('drop', function(e) {
    var str = e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.getData('Text');
    console.log(str);
    $('#return').html(str);
  });
});
```